# Why $99x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5 \implies (-1)x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Lastly I have read a example of some exercise. There was this statement:
$$99x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5\quad  \implies\quad (-1)x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
Can somebody explain that simple fact to me?

Comment: $99\equiv -1\pmod{5}$

Comment: Apply the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), using $\ 99\equiv 9\equiv -1\pmod{5}\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$99x^2\equiv_5100x^2-x^2\equiv_50-x^2\equiv_5-x^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Since we have $$99\equiv -1 \mod 5$$ this is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Because $99\equiv 4 \equiv -1 \mod 5$

Answer (score 2):

$$99\equiv 4=(5-1)\equiv -1 \pmod{5}$$

:)